# Convert JSON from Elasticsearch to Java Object

Tags: java, android, json, elasticsearch, httprequest

I have a problem with `gson.fromJson` function. I'm getting JSON from my ElasticSearch. I can convert the body to String but I can't convert this to object. Maybe I should use something else then Gson? Can someone help? 
Thank you in advance.

Get data and `gson.fromJson`:

```
 try {
    Response response = restClient.performRequest(
            "GET",
            "/elasticsearch/posts/car/_search",
            Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
            entity1);

    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    DataCar dataCar = gson.fromJson(responseBody, DataCar.class);
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    DataCar cars = gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(responseBody,DataCar.class);
    ArrayList<Car> carsList = cars.getCars();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JSON text:

```
 {
   "took":1,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},
   "hits":{"total":{"value":6,"relation":"eq"},
   "max_score":1.0,
   "hits": [{"_index":"posts","_type":"car","
    _id":"b9ZirGoByBAZW2S2ADLS","
   _score":1.0,
    "_source":{
      "image_url": "https://examplepicturelink.com/xyz.jpg",
      "brand": "Audi",
      "model": "A8",
      "price": "120000",
      "engine":"5.0",
      "year":"2018",
      "hp":"380",
      "mileage":"100",
      "color":"czarny",
      "damaged":"false",
      "automated":"true",
      "fuel":"true",
      "country_from":"Polska",
      "post_id":"123abc456d7",
      "url":"https://examplepicturelink.com/xyz.jpg",
      "region":"Kujawsko-pomorskie",
      "city":"Bydgoszcz",
      "description":"Samochód z salonu, bardzo polecam!",
      "created_at":"29-04-2019"
}} // and more records
```

Downloading data to application work good

DataCar and Car model:

```
public class DataCar {
public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void setCars(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}

private ArrayList<Car> cars;
}



import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Car {

@SerializedName("image_url")
private String image_url;
@SerializedName("brand")
private String brand;
@SerializedName("model")
private String model;
@SerializedName("price")
private Double price;
@SerializedName("engine")
private String engine;
@SerializedName("year")
private Integer year;
@SerializedName("hp")
private Integer hp;
@SerializedName("mileage")
private Integer mileage;
@SerializedName("color")
private String color;
@SerializedName("damaged")
private Boolean damaged;
@SerializedName("automated")
private Boolean automated;
@SerializedName("fuel")
private Boolean fuel;
@SerializedName("country_from")
private String country_from;
@SerializedName("post_id")
private String post_id;
@SerializedName("url")
private String url;
@SerializedName("region")
private String region;
@SerializedName("city")
private String city;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;
@SerializedName("created_at")
private String created_at;
//getters + setters + constructors
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use [FasterXML/Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) than "Google Gson" considering its capabilities. You would need following dependecies if you're using Maven to dependency management or add each of the dependecies to your `classpath` otherwise.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

For your problem you can try something like this to your POJO.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  // This will exclude null JSON attributes.
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // This will exclude any unknown(not available in the class) attribute in the JSON string.
public class Car {

    @JsonProperty("image_url") // No matter if you didn't use this annotation. Jackson will automatically bind the variable name.
    private String image_url;

    @JsonProperty("brand")
    private String brand;

    @JsonProperty("model")
    private String model;

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private Double price;

    @JsonProperty("engine")
    private String engine;

    @JsonProperty("year")
    private Integer year;

    @JsonProperty("hp")
    private Integer hp;

    @JsonProperty("mileage")
    private Integer mileage;

    @JsonProperty("color")
    private String color;

    // Omitted the rest.
}
```

To de-serialize the JSON string now you would need a function like this.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonProcessor { // This implementation can change as you want.

    public static <T> List<T> unmarshallToList(String json, Class<T> classType)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory() // Check here whether you can take different function to directly de-serialize to the object than to a List.
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, classType);

        return mapper.readValue(json, javaType);
    }
}
```

When you invoke the `unmarshallToList` function, you need to pass `JSON String` and the class type and the function will return `List` of your objects.

```
List<Car> cars = JsonProcessor.unmarshallToList(jsonString, Car.class);
```

If your JSON object doesn't work yet, try wrapping the JSON string with `[ ]` to imply it as a `JSON Array`.

> If you do any change to `unmarshallToList` function, you
>   need adjust your JSON string accordingly. Check [this
>   documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html) to understand what you can do to change the return
>   type of the function.